# Getting 404 in Laravel on Heroku server

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, heroku, gitlab, http-status-code-404

I am deploying my application from Gitlab using ci/cd, it's successfully deployed.

And it's also working on my local system and shared server but not working on Heroku

Also I also try to delete htaccess file but it is still not working.

```
{ "message": "", "exception":
"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
"file":
"/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/AbstractRouteCollection.php",
"line": 43, "trace": [
    {
        "file": "/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php",
        "line": 162,
        "function": "handleMatchedRoute",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\AbstractRouteCollection",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
        "line": 639,
        "function": "match",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
        "line": 628,
        "function": "findRoute",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
        "line": 617,
        "function": "dispatchToRoute",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
        "line": 165,
        "function": "dispatch",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 128,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
        "line": 21,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 167,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
        "line": 21,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 167,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php",
        "line": 27,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 167,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php",
        "line": 63,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 167,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/app/vendor/fruitcake/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php",
        "line": 37,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 167,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/app/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php",
        "line": 57,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 167,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 103,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
        "line": 140,
        "function": "then",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
        "line": 109,
        "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/app/public/index.php",
        "line": 55,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
        "type": "->"
    } ]
```

Comment: found any solution ?